# ST_Contains return wrong results

Tags: postgis

I have problem with ST_Contains

This query return false, but it have to be true.

```
SELECT ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((38.19715082645416 56.51095701071156, 39.20248601585627 55.9670496196438, 36.70775402337313 55.65737820522319,37.71308921277523 55.10132399348111,38.19715082645416 56.51095701071156))',4326),ST_GeomFromText('POINT( 37.6481888 55.822178 )',4326))
```

I checked it on the map

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order in your box's corners is wrong. Order **DOES** matter:

[image]

You can also verify with [st_isvalid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html) that something is wrong:

```
SELECT st_isvalid(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((38.19715082645416 56.51095701071156, 39.20248601585627 55.9670496196438, 36.70775402337313 55.65737820522319,37.71308921277523 55.10132399348111,38.19715082645416 56.51095701071156))',4326))

st_isvalid
-----------------
f
```

Comment: Swap points 3 and 4.